# how to iterate through list and save it to single excel file using python

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm iterating through list and storing values of each iteration to dataframe. I need to write the dataframe values to single excel sheet for all iterations, and their might be extra columns coming up in next iterations as well. How to solve this scenario and write all the data to single excel sheet for all iterations using python?

list  look like as below:

```
[
{
    "files": 0, 
    "data": [
        {"name": "RFC", "value": "XXXXXXX", "attId": 01}, 
        {"name": "NOMBRE", "value": "JOSE", "attId": 02}, 
        {"name": "APELLIDO PATERNO", "value": "MONTIEL", "attId": 03}, 
        {"name": "APELLIDO MATERNO", "value": "MENDOZA", "attId": 04}, 
        {"name": "FECHA NACIMIENTO", "value": "1989-02-04", "attId": 05}
    ], 
    "dirId": 1, 
    "docId": 4, 
    "structure": {
        "name": "personales", 
        "folioId": 22
    }
}, 
{
    "files": 1, 
    "data": [
        {"name": "CALLE", "value": "AMOR", "attId": 06}, 
        {"name": "No. EXTERIOR", "value": "4", "attId": 07}, 
        {"name": "No. INTERIOR", "value": "2", "attId": 08}, 
        {"name": "C.P.", "value": "55060", "attId": 09}, 
        {"name": "ENTIDAD", "value": "ESTADO DE MEXICO", "attId": 10}, 
        {"name": "MUNICIPIO", "value": "ECATEPEC", "attId": 11}, 
        {"name": "COLONIA", "value": "INDUSTRIAL", "attId": 12}
        ], 
    "dirId": 1, 
    "docId": 4, 
    "structure": {
        "name": "direccion", 
        "folioId": 22
        "add":"new oregon"
        "vehicle code":"2405"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: If you could manage to create the dataframe, why not just export to excel. Can you be more clear about your question. What is the problem?

Comment: as their are two jsons inside a list , im iterating both jsons, when i do the same i want to save it in same excel